# Append() не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делал разные тесты, пробовал вставлять готовый код, но все равно не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
jquery $('#articles').append("<p>" + data.name + "</p>");
    html код
    <div id="articles">

        <?php foreach ($data as $article): ?>
            <p><?php echo $article['name']; ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = { name: "test" };
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#articles').append("<p>" + data.name + "</p>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="articles">
</div>
```

Comment: Igor не работает, вообще не выводит ничего

Comment: @Zhandos Нажмите в ответе кнопку "Выполнить код". Ну как?

Comment: Igor здесь работает.
копирнул и вставил, но все равно у меня ничего не возвращает

Comment: @Zhandos Два варианта. 1. Пустое `data.name`. 2. Код вызывается до того, как на странице появляется элемент `<div id="articles">`.

Comment: Igor
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  var data = { name: "test" };
  $('#articles').append("<p>" + data.name + "</p>");
</script>

</head>
<body>


<div id="articles">


не выводит

Comment: @Zhandos Код вызывается до того, как на странице появляется элемент `<div id="articles">`.

Comment: Igor
спасибо! 
Моя ошибка

Comment: @Zhandos Пожалуйста. Успехов.

Comment: Igor и Вам успехов

Comment: @Zhandos Надо задать другой вопрос с кодом, который не работает.